# C++ Builder 11.1 - Problem with main menus and Styles

Tags: c++, styles, c++builder-11-alexandria

I am trying to upgrade a project from C++Builder 10.3.1 to 11.1, and have a problem with the MainMenu not painting properly in 11.1 when Styles are used.

It works fine in 10.3.1, but in 11.1, when any style OTHER than `Windows` is used, it doesn't paint properly.

Any ideas as to why this is happening?

I tried using an ActionMenuBar, ActionManager, and an ActionList, but it keeps coming up with syntax errors in the `Vcl.ActnMan.hpp` file:

> [bcc32 Error] Vcl.ActnMan.hpp(1496): E2293 ) expected

```
class PASCALIMPLEMENTATION TActionBarStyleList : public System::Classes::TStringList
{
    typedef System::Classes::TStringList inherited;
    
private:
    TActionBarStyle* __fastcall GetStyle(int Index);
    
public:
    __property TActionBarStyle* Style[int Index] = {read=GetStyle};
public:
    /* TStringList.Create */ inline __fastcall TActionBarStyleList()/* overload */ : System::Classes::TStringList() { };
    /* TStringList.Create */ inline __fastcall TActionBarStyleList(bool OwnsObjects)/* overload */ : System::Classes::TStringList(OwnsObjects) { };
    /* TStringList.Create */ inline __fastcall TActionBarStyleList(System::WideChar QuoteChar, System::WideChar Delimiter)/* overload */ : System::Classes::TStringList(QuoteChar, Delimiter) { };

// This next line is where the error occurs

    /* TStringList.Create */ inline __fastcall TActionBarStyleList(System::WideChar QuoteChar, System::WideChar Delimiter, System::Classes::TStringsOptions Options)/* overload */ : System::Classes::TStringList(QuoteChar, Delimiter, Options) { };
    /* TStringList.Create */ inline __fastcall TActionBarStyleList(System::Types::TDuplicates Duplicates, bool Sorted, bool CaseSensitive)/* overload */ : System::Classes::TStringList(Duplicates, Sorted, CaseSensitive) { };
    /* TStringList.Destroy */ inline __fastcall virtual ~TActionBarStyleList() { }
    
};
```

p[image: Image capture of main menu not painting properly]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1nxL.png)

Comment: StackOverflow is a Q&A site, not a debugging service. This sounds like a bug/regression that you need to [report to Embarcadero](https://quality.embarcadero.com)

Comment: This is very strange behavior Remy.  I would like to use the Main Menu as is because this is a Win32 VCL application and it's also an MDI app which means the child windows have their own menus which merge with the main menu.  Don't know why this doesn't work in 11.1 but works fine in 10.3.1.

Comment: See my previous comment again.

Comment: Sent it into Embercadero and it has an RSP-38002 number assigned to it.

Comment: Remy,  Sadly there are way too many bugs in this compiler to warrant me using it.  I will have to keep using 10.3.1.  I also noticed that child windows in an MDI application are not being created properly if I select Window State = wsMaximized.  Wayyyy too many bugs to warrant upgrading at this point.

Comment: Remy,  Found out what was causing the menus to not work properly in C++ Builder 11.1.  Seems the menu OnDrawItem procedure doesn't work.  I also tested this in 10.4.2 and same result.  I just removed the OnDrawItem from the menus and it works fine now in 11.1